# How to annotate the SwitchGear gene models?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-annotation, chip-seq

According to this page(http://switchgeargenomics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/switchdb_technote1.pdf), the SwitchGear gene models can be annotated by the NCBI annotation associated with Refseq accession numbers, but I couldn't find such information in this page(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/), which is indicated in the above pdf page...

How can I annotate the SwitchGear gene models?